# Adding trailing stop-loss to tradingview strategy in pine editor

Tags: pine-script, editor, pine-script-v4

How can I add trailing stop loss to this code below?

```
//@version=4
strategy("1 min scalping", overlay=true)

// Stochastic Conditions with 5, 3, 3 parameters for scalping
stochK = sma(stoch(close, high, low, 5), 3)
stochD = sma(stochK, 3)

// Exponential Moving Averages
ema50 = ema(close, 50)
ema100 = ema(close, 100)



// Long Condition
longCondition = stochK > 20 and ema50 > ema100

// Short Condition
shortCondition = stochK < 80 and ema50 < ema100 

strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, 100000, when=longCondition)
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, 100000, when=shortCondition)

strategy.exit("Take Profit/Stop Loss", loss = 30, profit = 60)
```

I've tried adjusting the code like this :

```
//@version=4
strategy("1 min scalping", overlay=true)

// Stochastic Conditions with 5, 3, 3 parameters for scalping
stochK = sma(stoch(close, high, low, 5), 3)
stochD = sma(stochK, 3)

// Exponential Moving Averages
ema50 = ema(close, 50)
ema100 = ema(close, 100)

// Define trailing stop parameters
trailOffset = input(10, title="Trail Offset in Pips")
trailOffsetPoints = trailOffset / syminfo.mintick
trailTrigger = input(20, title="Trail Trigger in Pips")
trailTriggerPoints = trailTrigger / syminfo.mintick

// Initialize trailing stop variables
var float longTrailingStop = na
var float shortTrailingStop = na

// Long Condition
longCondition = stochK > 20 and ema50 > ema100

// Short Condition
shortCondition = stochK < 80 and ema50 < ema100

if (longCondition)
    longTrailingStop := high - trailOffsetPoints
    if (low[1] < (high - trailTriggerPoints))
        longTrailingStop := high[1] - trailOffsetPoints

if (shortCondition)
    shortTrailingStop := low + trailOffsetPoints
    if (high[1] > (low + trailTriggerPoints))
        shortTrailingStop := low[1] + trailOffsetPoints

// Enter long and short trades with trailing stop
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=longCondition)
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when=shortCondition)

// Exit trades with fixed take profit and stop loss
strategy.exit("Take Profit/Stop Loss", loss = 30, profit = 60)

// Implement trailing stops
strategy.exit("Long Trailing Stop", from_entry="Long", when=longCondition and low < longTrailingStop)
strategy.exit("Short Trailing Stop", from_entry="Short", when=shortCondition and high > shortTrailingStop)
```

But then the stop loss and take profit levels are not respected and they go as they please.
It seems like the trailing is working on both sides sometimes.

Idealy it would be to set the stop loss and take profit as 60:30 pips, but when the price goes 5 or more pips to profit, the trailing stop loss will start following it.

Thank you in advance :)